# How to replace Ubuntu with Windows 8.1

Tags: system-installation

How can I replace ubuntu with Windows 8.1?

I got my Windows CD, but Ubuntu cannot read it or I just don't know how to run it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot from the disc. To do this, assuming your BIOS supports booting from a disc, put the disc into the disc drive and turn your computer off. Next, when you first turn your computer on, interrupt your BIOS. Usually this is done with the F12, Delete, or Escape keys. That should bring up an option to boot from the disc. Choose that, and the Windows installation screen should come up.

Comment: I did try doing this. It's no where in the BIOS!

Comment: @StevenFordGamatan What motherboard do you have? I might be able to do some research on the BIOS to find the option.

Comment: Now that I think about it, there must be an option, or you wouldn't have been able to install Ubuntu, unless it came preinstalled.